# The issue when using popen and pclose

Tags: c, shell, unix

I have a program which uses `popen` and `pclose`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    int ret_val = 0;

    fp = popen("ls *", "r");
    if (NULL == fp)
    {
        printf("popen error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    ret_val = pclose(fp);
    if (-1 == ret_val)
    {
        printf("pclose error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d,%d,%d\n",ret_val, WIFEXITED(ret_val), WEXITSTATUS(ret_val));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program is:

```
./test
Broken Pipe
36096,1,141
```

My questions are:

1. Why is there a "Broken pipe"?
2. Why is the exit status code 141? I think "ls *" executed
   successfully and therefore, the exit status should be 0.

Comment: do you understand pipes in Unix? For example do you know what goes on when you type `cat /etc/motd | more` on the command line?

Comment: @AhmedMasud: cat /etc/motd | more: The output of cat /etc/motd will be the input of more. Is it right? Thanks for your advice!

Comment: @AhmedMasud: I know, because there is a "broken pipe", the "ls *" doesn't execute successfully. So the exit status is 141. But why there is a "broken pipe"? I can't figure out the root cause.

Comment: @AhmedMasud:I think the "Broken pipe" is outputed by "ls *". Because My program doesn't use fgets to get the output, and close the pipe directly. The "ls *" outputs "Broken pipe". Is it right?

Comment: @AnishRam: I agree with your explanation. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- "Broken pipe" is displayed by `ls` because the SIGPIPE signal is
  raised.
- SIGPIPE is raised because `ls` is trying to output to a closed pipe.
- The pipe is closed because your program immediately calls `pclose()` after your `popen()`.

This behaviour of `pclose` can be further understood by reading [the documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/pclose.html). Basically, `pclose` will:

1. Close a stream opened by a `popen()` call.
2. Wait for the command to terminate.
3. Return the termination status of the command.

Since it closes the stream *and then* waits for the command to terminate, `ls` can sometimes try to write to the stream *after* it was closed hence causing the mentioned scenario.

Additionally, as kingsindian pointed out, SIGPIPE may not be raised always. This is because the command can actually finish doing its work *before* the main process calls `pclose()`. Since this behaviour is unpredictable, I suggest implementing some synchronization. You always want to know **exactly** what state your program is in at all times.

As a side note, pipes were meant for inter-process communication. If your main process *just* opens and closes a pipe, you might be better off using `fork()` and `exec()`.

Comment: I agree with your explanation. Thanks very much!

Comment: +1, It's not always going to happen. It really depends how quick the `ls` is compared to your program. You get broken pipe because the output of ls is still in the pipe but pipe's write descriptor is no longer there. For example, you won't see the error if you do `sleep(1)` before closing the pipe as there's enough time to write the data. But there's no reason to open a pipe for read if you are not really going to read from it.

Comment: @kingsindian, Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

It works with sleep() before closing the pipe but I had to set 10  seconds (sleep(10)) based on my command.

Comment: This is true, but note that Anish Ramaswamy's answer explains _why_ the `sleep()` will make it work.

Comment: Yes I agree with him